# Error (ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED): Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, discord.js, raspberry-pi3

I'm getting this error when I run my discord bot on my raspberry pi. It worked everytime when I run it on my windows machine. I installed FFmpeg with sudo apt-get install ffmpeg. I don't know if I need to install something else for ffmpeg on my raspberry pi
This is the error I'm getting

```
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:399:19)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at PassThrough.ondata (_stream_readable.js:718:22)
    at PassThrough.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at PassThrough.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at PassThrough.Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:152:32)
    at PassThrough.afterTransform (_stream_transform.js:96:10)
Emitted 'error' event on FFmpeg instance at:
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)
    at FFmpeg.onerror (_stream_readable.js:754:7)
    at FFmpeg.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Socket.processError (node_modules/prism-media/src/core/FFmpeg.js:64:40)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:418:5)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:445:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:399:11)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED'
}
```

Normally it should play an audio stream to a discord channel.
I don't think my code is wrong, because it's working on my other computer.
My code:

```
let stream;
//Meme.url is just a youtube link, like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
stream = ytdl(meme.url, {
    filter: "audioonly",
    opusEncoded: true,
    encoderArgs: ['-af', "dynaudnorm=f=150"]
}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
    try {
        song_queue.connection.play(stream, { type: "opus" })
        .on('finish', () => {
            
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        message.channel.send("Error while the meme song");
    }
```